# How do I fix a web page showing fine on PC but appearing tiny on mobile

Tags: web, responsive

If you look at my website at vrbluedog.com, you can see that the home page and venue pages appear fine on PC and mobile phones, but the navigation pages (which you can see by clicking the "Find VR Service") appear tiny on mobile phones.

Can someone please tell me what code I need to add to make the navigation pages appear readable on mobile phones?

Thanks a lot guys,

Ana

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this html tag is inside your meta on all pages.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Here is an explanation on what this tag is, and why it is needed for mobile websites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag